# Can't access indexes other than 0

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a program to quickly rename some files in a folder.

The files are named like this:

C:\Users\user\Documents\Reports\Report *FirstName* *LastName*.*FileNameExtension*

I'd like to rename them like this:

C:\Users\user\Documents\Reports\Report *LastName* *FirstName*.*FileNameExtension*

This is my code so far:

```
public class FileRenamer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

        try(Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(args[0]))) {
            paths.forEach(filePath -> {
                filePaths.add(filePath.toString());
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        filePaths.forEach(filePath -> {

            String[] splitPath = filePath.split(" ");
            String fileNameExtension = splitPath[2].split(".")[1];
            splitPath[2] = splitPath[2].split(".")[0];

            String newFilePath = splitPath[0] + " " + splitPath[2] + " " + 
                                 splitPath[1] + "." + fileNameExtension;

            new File(filePath).renameTo(new File(newFilePath));

        });

    }

}
```

My problem is that it keeps throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for the splitPath array. But it doesn't throw an exception when I'm running a for-loop to output the indexes from 0 to 2. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is the working for-loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < splitPath.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + splitPath[i]);
}
```

It outputs this to the console:

```
0: C:\Users\user\Documents\Reports\Report
1: FirstName
2: LastName.FileNameExtension
```

Comment: Perhaps it finds a file with a name that doesn't fit the pattern. Try printing the file name.

Comment: Also, if you're using the new `Path` API, why are you doing the rename using the old `File` API, instead of calling [`Files.move()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)?

Comment: Thank you @Andreas
Some people do have middle names after all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Files.walk()` not only prints the regular files in the directory, but also the directory itself and any hidden files. Those will likely not fit your pattern.

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/joost"), 1).forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.toString()));

/home/joost
/home/joost/someRegularFile.jpg
/home/joost/.profile
...
```

Also, `Path::toString()` gives to the full path, not just the filename. So if any of the directories in your path has a space in it, you will get unexpected results.